# Altering string variable storing xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

```
string content = ....
```

I have some XML content stored in a string as shown in the variable above. The content stored is similar to below ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <ItemModel xsi:type="TypeKeep">
      <Name>Name01</Name>
    </ItemModel>
    <ItemModel xsi:type="TypeDelete">
      <Name>Name02</Name>
    </ItemModel>
    <ItemModel xsi:type="TypeDelete">
      <Name>Name03</Name>
    </ItemModel>
  </Items>
</model>
```

In here I want to remove all the elements which have the type="TypeDelete" . In the sense I am trying to alter the content variable by removing the elments of TypeDelete

Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace xsiNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");

            List<XElement> removeNodes = doc.Descendants("ItemModel").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type") == "TypeDelete").ToList();

            for (int i = removeNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                removeNodes[i].Remove();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: any way I can make a connection between the content variable ? that is shown in my code snippet

Comment: I updated code to read a string. You use the Parse() method for a string and a Load() method for a file or steam.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a specific XML node from an XML file directly you can go through this link and [try this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/delete-xml-node-using-c-sharp1)